# RequireJS paths are different depending on how page is accessed

Tags: asp.net, requirejs

I'm having issues with loading a web page using RequireJS depending on how the page is accessed.

The webpage can be accessed through the following links because of how the view controllers are set up

1. `www.mydomain.com` works
2. `www.mydomain.com/home` works
3. `www.mydomain.com/home/` does not work
4. `www.mydomain.com/home/index` does not work
5. `www.mydomain.com/home/index/` does not work

If the webpage is accessed from the first two links, then RequireJS can find the files it needs looking for them at `www.mydomain.com/Scripts/main.js`

If the webpage is accessed using 3 or 4 then I am getting 404 file not found errors, and RequireJS is looking for files at `www.mydomain.com/home/Scripts/main.js`

If the webpage is accessed using 5 then it is the same thing, but RequireJS is looking for files at `www.mydomain.com/home/index/Scripts/main.js`

Is there a way to direct RequireJS to the correct paths no matter how the page is accessed, or is there a way in Asp.Net to disable the use of paths 3-5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to define my `baseUrl` more specifically. I had a config defined for require that specified relative paths to my required modules, but I also had a relative `baseUrl` which was causing my problems. I was having problems resolving all of the paths because this web site is going to be installed on various roots and with different sub application or endpoint names. My solution, ultimately, was to calculate my `baseUrl` dynamically.

```
let port = document.location.port ? ':' + document.location.port : '';
//config is a custom object and endpoint name is the ASP.NET application name.
let endpointName = '//' + config.endpointName;
let root = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + port + endpointName;

var require = {
    baseUrl: root,
    paths: {
        'module': '/Path/to/module',
        ...
    }
};
```